# Launch VIM and show, or hide, row numbers

Tags: command-line, bash, vim, syntax, command-line-arguments

### Background

Control whether row numbers are displayed after vim starts (in a non-interactive mode).

### Problem

A shell script contains the following code:

```
echo Converting $1 to $1.html...

NUMBERS="-c set number"
if [ "$2" == "" ]; then
  NUMBERS=
fi

vim -e $1 -c "set nobackup" $NUMBERS -c ":colorscheme moria" \
  -c :TOhtml \
  -c wq  -c :q
```

The script (`src2png.sh`) is invoked as:

```
./src2png.sh src2png.sh
```

And also invoked as:

```
./src2png.sh src2png.sh numbers
```

In the second case, vim should be started with numbers along the left-hand side. (The word "numbers" can be anything, so long as it is not empty.) I have tried several syntactical variations without success:

```
NUMBERS=-c "set number"
NUMBERS="-c set number"
NUMBERS="-c 'set number'"
NUMBERS="-c \":set number\""
```

All of these fail when starting vim, for various reasons. (Usually, "Error detected while processing command line:".)

### Question

What is the correct syntax to allow a second command-line parameter to control whether or not vim starts with row numbers displayed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
vim -e $1 -c "set nobackup" ${2:+"-c set number"} -c "colorscheme moria" \
-c TOhtml \
-c wq -c q
```

See the bash(1) man page, the section on Parameter Expansion for an explanation of how that works.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `NUMBERS` to an array:

```
NUMBERS=(-c set number)
```

or use `NUMBERS` as a flag and do:

```
NUMBERS=flag
if [ "$2" == "" ]; then
    NUMBERS=
fi

vim -e $1 -c "set nobackup" ${NUMBERS:+-c set number} -c ":colorscheme moria" \
```

Please see also [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: The BashFAQ you linked to is well worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack would be to use sh -c, like so:

```
NUMBERS="-c ':set number'"
sh -c "vim $NUMBERS"
```

This does start another shell process, so if you're worried about overhead, instead you might try having $NUMBERS either contain ":set number" or a no-operation like ":", thus:

```
vim -c "$NUMBERS"
```

Comment: Looks like there were other problems with the source. Missing quotes on other items, for example.

Comment: Instead of `sh -c "vim $NUMBERS"` you could use `eval vim $NUMBERS`. Then you wouldn't be spawning another process. You do have to be careful about how `eval` transforms your other arguments, though.